# OpenCV Threading Capture Loses Connection to IP Camera

Tags: multithreading, opencv, ffmpeg, camera, python-3.7

I have a surveillance program that opens 16 threads to check on to 16 different cameras with live video, but when after some time (20/30 seconds) cameras starts to lose frames and I need to reconnect them.

The thing is that if I only open 10 streams at once it might lose a frame from time to time, but if I open 16 streams it begins to fail every 20 seconds or so.

I've checked system params, and CPU doesnt go more than 50% and RAM is on 4GB, so this doesnt look like the problem.
Also I've checked the network and it's fine, no delay and no packet loss.

Sometime I get `error while decoding MB 8 7, bytestream -5`

This is the thread I use to get the streams.

````
    """
    Class that continuously gets frames from a VideoCapture object
    with a dedicated thread.
    """
    def __init__(self, idcam,ipcamara, user, passwd,resolucionh,resolucionw):
        self.id = idcam
        self.ip = ipcamara
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.Q =[]
        self.scale_percent = 50
        self.i = 0

    def start(self):
        self.conectar()
        Thread(target=self.get, args=()).start()
        return self

    def get(self):

        while True:
            if(self.stream.isOpened() and self.online):
                (status, preFrame) = self.stream.read()
                if(status):
                    self.frame = (preFrame)
                else:
                    self.stream.release()
                    self.online = False
            else:
                graba_log('Camara '+str(self.id),'Desconexion')
                self.conectar()
                time.sleep(1)

    def conectar(self):
        print('Iniciando conexion con camara '+str(self.id))
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://"+self.user+":"+self.passwd+"@"+self.ip)
        self.online = True
    def recuperarFrame(self):
        return self.frame ```
````

Comment: 16 threads, 16 cameras, 4 gb ram... When you just tried with 3 cameras, do you still get the same problem?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk No, when I have 3 cameras work perfect and no disconnections.